# Latest possible FILETIME

Tags: c++, windows, utc, filetime

I'm creating a mock object to test my application so that it works at the boundary conditions of time. I'm using [`FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284.aspx) in the Windows SDK.

The link shows the earliest time which is January 1, 1601 (I'm assuming midnight 00:00:00 and both `dwLowDateTime` and `dwHighDateTime` are `0x00000000`), so I have that. What is the latest possible FILETIME?

My first instinct is to set `dwLowDateTime` and `dwHighDateTime` to `0xFFFFFFFF`, but then I questioned if that really is a valid time that I need to test, due to where my linked page says the [`SetFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724933) function uses `0xFFFFFFFF` to specify that a file's previous access time should be preserved.

Comment: if you are looking to store information about file edits shouldn't you limit the changes to before the current time? It's makes no sense to have a last-modified time in the future.

Comment: @tmain249 I certainly could use current time, and that would work if my question isn't answered. Thanks for the comment. I'm actually testing recorded video for like a security camera which of course requires a time stamp for each frame.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My understanding is that `FILETIME` was made to represent any valid [`SYSTEMTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724950) in 64 bits. If you take the limit of `SYSTEMTIME` (last millisecond in 30827) then you end up with a `FILETIME` of `0x7fff35f4f06c58f0` by using [`SystemTimeToFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948).

However, if you put `0x7fffffffffffffff` into [`FileTimeToSystemTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280) then you will end up in the year 30828, although this date is invalid for `SYSTEMTIME`. Any larger value (`0x8000000000000000` and above) causes `FileTimeToSystemTime()` to fail.

All in all, I would recommend not to go beyond `0x7fff35f4f06c58f0` in order to stay compatible with `SYSTEMTIME`.

Comment: According to the patent linked by @NickShaw the FILETIME has a range of +/- 30,000 years from its epoch of 1601.  The actual range, however, is only +/- 29,227 (and some slop) from the epoch.  And SYSTEMTIME is supposed to be from year 0 to year 65,535.  So Microsoft didn't bother to accurately implement what they patented. :)

Answer (score 6):

According to the link, FILETIME represents:

> ...the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since **January 1, 1601** (UTC).

so not Jan 1st 1970.

It also says

> ...the SetFileTime function [for example] uses 0xFFFFFFFF to specify that a file's previous access time should be preserved.

So I don't think you would expect 0xFFFFFFFF to be a valid max value.

According to [patent 6853957](http://www.patentstorm.us/patents/6853957/description.html), the range is 30,000 years before/after the epoch (Jan 1, 1601).  That implies you can use it with negative dates (i.e. dates before the epoch) too.

EDIT: Just calculated: it can store (approx) 58,454 days worth of 100-nanosecond intervals, so +/- 30,000 years sounds like a good value to go with, if you accept negative dates of course.

Comment: No problem. :)  I'd also suggest that maybe you should do a reality test on the date instead of just boundary checking - anything beyond, say, the year 2100 is bound to be wrong... (unless your writing a game set in the distant future of course!)

Comment: True - we don't know yet on what weekday april 3, 31601 will fall.

Comment: Even though the patent says FILETIME is +/- 30,000 years, it is actually a little less. 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF / 10,000,000 / 86,400 / 365.242198 is 29,227 years.  So pick your programming limits accordingly.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, just because we aren't sure yet on 4000-year leap year rule.

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer in this MSDN article - [Test Cases for the RTC Real-Time Functions Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330911%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx):

> The test looks for the range beginning with the minimum possible FILETIME (FILETIME 0 is the start of Jan 1st 1601) and end with maximum possible FILETIME (Max FILETIME is the maximum 64-bit value).