# time.time() overflow/rollover

Tags: python, time

So I am using time.time() in my python module to track execution time and act as a while loop escape upon timeout.

My question is when does time.time() rollover/overflow. Or does it? I don't fully comprehend python datatypes yet, so I am not sure how far it can keep increasing.

Comment: related: [Get the highest possible `gmtime()` for any architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32045725/4279)

Comment: related: [How does python's time.time() method work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27830403/4279)

Comment: related: [Latest possible FILETIME](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9999393/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a while. `time.time()` returns the time in seconds  since the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing) as a `float`. On UNIX machines the epoch is usually 1970-1-1. IIRC, the epoch on windows is 1601-1-1.

According to `sys.float_info`:

```
In [2]: sys.float_info
Out[2]: sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

So we have

```
In [3]: 1.7976931348623157e+308/(3600*24*365.0)
Out[3]: 5.700447535712569e+300
```

years before rollover. :-)

Comment: Good to hear! If this project is still going years from now, I have bigger problems. Thanks!

Comment: 1- the epoch for `time.time()` is still  `1970` even  on Windows (check `time.gmtime(0).year`). The [underlying implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27830403/4279) does uses 1601 and 100 nanoseconds ticks returned by `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` but it is not visible from Python (python sees "seconds since Epoch" value). 2- [Valid timestamps (`time_t`) are far less than `sys.float_info.max`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32045725/4279). It is as small as something like ~3000 years on Windows. Though the actual `time.time()` limit (max `FILETIME`) is less than 30828 years on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using time.clock() would be more accurate.

Comment: clock() has higher precision which is not the same as accuracy

Comment: but precision is very similar to being exact and when you are being exact you are being accurate you are just playing with words, nothing helpful is being said.

Comment: They are different terms - http://kaffee.50webs.com/Science/images/Accuracy-vs-precision1.jpg

Comment: again, seriously."The state or quality of being precise" is exactly what precision means.and when we say something is precise we say that it is accurate.these are all synonyms,perhaps different words but same meaning.

Comment: OK. I see now that time.time() actually has more precision that time.clock(). nvm.