# python - issues with time.clock()/time()

Tags: python, time

I wrote a system to exchange crc-checked struct data between an arduino nano and my python script. This is working pretty well but when i let the system run i get unexpected output on my python monitor (using pycharm)

print "Took ", (time.time() - timeout), " s" sometimes prints out Took  0.0  s.
Usually it prints Took  0.0160000324249  s.
Using win7-64bit professional.

From time doc : *Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.*

I´m looking for something like millis() thats enough precision for my case

Code Python :

```
import serial
import time
import binascii
import struct
from ctypes import *    

arduino = serial.Serial()
def receive_struct2():
  start = 0x85
  detected_start = False
  arduino.baudrate = 57600
  arduino.timeout = 0
  arduino.port = 'COM8'
  try:
    arduino.open()
  except serial.SerialException, e:
    print e

  while True:
     if(arduino.inWaiting() >= 1 and detected_start == False):
        data = ord(arduino.read())
        if data == start:
          print "Detected begin"
          detected_start = True
        else: print chr(data),

     if arduino.inWaiting() >= 1 and detected_start == True:
       message_length = ord(arduino.read())
       #print "Got message length ", message_length
       timeout = time.time()
       while time.time() - timeout <= 0.3 and arduino.inWaiting() <  message_length-1:pass
       print "Took ", (time.time() - timeout), " s"
       ....
```

Comment: unrelated: there should be a way to wait for I/O without a busy loop (`select()` analog on Windows) check aurdino API doc. A better way to implement a busy loop is to use a deadline: `deadline = timer() + 0.3; while timer() < deadline and ...`. Note: there are different useful timer definitions: system-wide vs. process-wide value, known-origin vs. only relative values are useful, count sleep time and/or time in child processes or not, etc. For example read [`time.monotonic()`, `time.perf_counter()`, `time.process_time()`  definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: Use [`timeit.default_timer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) instead of `time.time()`, to measure a short duration.

---

16ms error for `time.time()` is not surprising on Windows.

Currently, Python uses `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` to implement `time.time()` on Windows that has  the resolution (precision) of 0.1ms (instead of `ftime()`'s 1ms) and the accuracy is between 0.5 ms and 15 ms (you could change it system-wide using `NtSetTimerResolution()`). See Python bug: [Use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` to get a resolution of 100 ns on Windows](http://bugs.python.org/issue13845) and another SO question: [How does python's time.time() method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27830403/4279)

A better alternative to measure short time intervals on Windows is to use `time.clock()` that is implemented using `QueryPerformanceCounter()` on Windows. For portability, you could use [`timeit.default_timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) that is assigned to `time.clock()` on Windows, `time.time()` on other systems, and it is [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) since Python3.3. See [Python - time.clock() vs. time.time() - accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85451/4279)