# Python: Clock source for Time module

Tags: python, time

There was no code have been wrote for this question and I was curious about how the time module counts time elapsed in execution. I read Python documentation and the clue that I have it depends on processor time.

Therefore would it be correct if I think that Python time module depends on processor crystal oscillator to keep track of the time elapsed in execution? Or it depends on some other hardware to keep track of time?

If the thought of it depends on crystal oscillator is correct, would it be for an execution to stop at certain line of code like **time.sleep(10)** forever as it was waiting for the time to reach?

One more question.. Is it possible to run an execution if time module is not needed in an execution? I guess it is possible to run because the execution doesn't need to know any information of time?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830403/how-does-pythons-time-time-method-work

Comment: `time` depends on the OS, first of all. And how the OS measures time and provides the measurements to Python - that's a whole different question. The computer might have different (hardware) clocks with different accuracies.