# My python code occasionally takes 15 milliseconds to execute an empty method

Tags: python

I created a simple application, and I realised that my code is running extremely slow. This application included calling the same method over and over again. I tried investigating the problem, and it turned out that calling the same function / method several times resulted in Python sometimes taking 15 milliseconds to execute an empty function (pass).

I'm running windows 10 Home 64 bit on a Lenovo ThinkPad, i7 CPU
The less code the function / method has, the smaller the chance of having a 15ms runtime, however, it never goes away.

Here's the code:

```
import time

class Clock:

    def __init__(self):
        self.t = time.time()

    def restart(self):
        dt = time.time() - self.t
        t = time.time()
        return dt * 1000


def method():
    pass



for i in range(100000):
    c = Clock()

    dt = c.restart()
    if dt > 1.:
        print(str(i) + ' ' + str(dt))
```

I'd expect that I never get anything printed out, however an average result looks like this:

> 6497 15.619516372680664
>
> 44412 15.622615814208984
>
> 63348 15.621185302734375

On average 1-4 out of 100000 times the time elapsed between starting the clock and getting the result (which is an empty function call and a simple subtraction and variable assignment) the elapsed time is 15.62.. milliseconds, which makes the run time really slow.
Occasionally the elapsed time is 1 millisecond.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 15.6 ms is the timer resolution on your Windows system.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, forgot to call the method in between the time measurement, but the problem still occurs, no matter what. With and without the call.

Comment: But "restart" is not empty: it calls time.time twice and makes a multiplication

Comment: What do you get if you just run `time.time()` repeatedly in a loop? Do you ever get anything between 0 and 15.6?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are making the call to `time.time()` twice which would require the system to retrieve the time from the OS. You can read here 
[How does python's time.time() method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830403/how-does-pythons-time-time-method-work)

As you mentioned you used Windows, it is probably better for you to use `time.clock()` instead and will defer you to read this link instead since they do a much better job explaining. https://www.pythoncentral.io/measure-time-in-python-time-time-vs-time-clock/

Also the link takes garbage collection into account of performance and gives the ability to remove it during testing.

Hope it answers your questions!